# Setting a variable name in the JSON

Tags: javascript, json

How can i set variables in JSON using javascript? I am using a javascript code to create a json but need the value set as a variable for one of the key value combinations. Eg-

```
<script>
    var formname="abc";
    var action_param = '{"key1":"hardcoded","key2":"harcoded","FormName":{formname}}';
    var gadget = document.getElementById("gadget123");
    gadget.setAttribute("JSONData", action_param);
</script>
```

I want the "FormName":{formname} to have the value whatever i set in the variable formname. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: *Don't create JSON by hand.* If you make an object and then `JSON.stringify()` it, this problem solves itself.

Answer (score 1):

Create an JS object, convert it to JSON with [stringify](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

```js
var formname="abc";
var obj = {
    "key1": "hardcoded",
    "key2": "hardcoded",
    formname
}
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(json)
```

---

`"formname": formname` can be simplified to just `forname` due to JS's [Object shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)

Comment: `{..., formname: formname}` would do just fine as well…

Comment: or just `{..., formname}`

Comment: Yea, this could be a lot shorter, but not sue if OP would understand, I'll try to add some more info ;)

Answer (score -2):

Probably you are looking [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
You can declare string literals using backtick(`)

To use a value of variable in your string

```js
var formname="abc";
    var action_param = `{"key1":"hardcoded","key2":"harcoded","FormName":"${formname}"}`
    
 console.log(JSON.parse(action_param));
```

Comment: That creates invalid JSON. Again, you should never create JSON by hand because it's very easy to make mistakes.